# Authenticating if a Facebook account exists - don't want to go through FB login

Tags: php, regex, facebook

I'd like to figure out a way to authenticate a facebook account on a form, without having to go into facebook login and whatnot.

So my question, is there anyway to check, I was thinking maybe the markup with regex, where I could check to see if a facebook count exists, and if so do something.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Not really clear what you mean by "maybe the markup with regex"...? What's the context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Graph API to check if an object for said user exists. (e.g., https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor).

From the [reference page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api):

> Alternatively, people and pages with
>   usernames can be fetched using their
>   username as an ID. Since "platform" is
>   the username for the page above,
>   https://graph.facebook.com/platform
>   will return what you expect. All
>   responses are JSON objects.

...though I'm not really sure how the relation username <-> ID is established. The preferred access is through ID: https://graph.facebook.com/220439

Hope this helps.