# How to connect to facebook database through FQL

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

I was wondering if you could help. I am currently writing some PHP code as part of a task I have set myself. What I want to do is on my page to simply type in a User ID for one of my friends on facebook, and use some FQL queries (I have written all the queries I need) to get the required information and then display that information back on my page. Here is what I have so far:

```
if ($_POST) {

$userID = $_REQUEST['userID'];

    if (empty($userID)) {

        echo "You have not entered all of the required fields";
}
else
{

        $query = "SELECT message FROM status WHERE uid = $userID"; 
        $result = $query; 
        echo $query;
}
}
?>
<form method="post" action="" name ="facebook" >
<div class="input1">Facebook User ID: <input class ="name" name="userID" type="text" id="userID" value=""/>
<input class="sub1" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></form>
```

I have managed to get this to work so that it simply echoes back the query on the submit button. How do I connect to the Facebook API to actually echo back some results from the query? Is this even possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using a search engine? http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/308888/Check-if-user-exist-in-facebook or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408193/authenticating-if-a-facebook-account-exists-dont-want-to-go-through-fb-login

Comment: You are really at the starting point. Just start reading documentation from here: http://developers.facebook.com